# pdftk command to disable software printing

Tags: security, pdf, pdftk

I know that using pdftk we can disable or allow printing of PDF. But what I really want to do is allow printing from hardware but disable software printing like Adobe reader print to PDF or Microsoft print to PDF.
Because software printing removes protection control over PDF.

If pdftk can't do it then is there any command line which can protect PDF.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, neither with pdftk nor with any other tool; it is not supported by the PDF format.

Also, keep in mind that PDF permissions are more of a suggestion than a real restriction, since it is up to the reader software to honour them. They are as secure as a stack of bills with "do not steal" written on a post-it note.

Comment: ok. I thought it same. Thanks for confirming. :)